# Very unorthodox placement of if-else clauses in C for handling special cases

Tags: c, formatting

I've encountered a situation with an if-else clause. Specifically, the positive case has only 1 expression, whereas the negative case is a sequence of statements wrapped in braces. Like this:

```
if( i >= list->count ) *result = 0; else
{
    *result = i * 32 + 31;
    while( mask >> (*result % 32) ) (*result)--;
}
```

I personally don't see this as bad formatting, as it's common to see something like this in POSIX shell scripts:

```sh
if [ "not-null-string" ] ; then
    # the "then" clause didn't start on a new line
    commands >redirections | pipeline
fi
```

And sometimes, the condition can be even more complex in shell scripts (at least, I may write that way if I see fit and logically intuitive)

But I know, the better style of writing that if-else clause should be like this:

```
if( i < list->count )
{
    *result = i * 32 + 31;
    while( mask >> (*result % 32) ) (*result)--;
}
else *result = 0;
```

So is there some kind of strong arguments against if-else clause formatting such as that in my first fragment of C code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the strong argument against the first example is that the `else` block starts right below the `if` and can be confused with a `then` block at first sight.

It's not about the order of the clauses, but only about formatting.
This is has the same condition and clauses, but it's not ambiguous:

```
if( i >= list->count )
    *result = 0;
else
{
    *result = i * 32 + 31;
    while( mask >> (*result % 32) ) (*result)--;
}
```

That said, I would personally prefer this formatting (though this second rewrite is less important and more subjective than the previous one):

```
if( i >= list->count )
    *result = 0;
else {
    *result = i * 32 + 31;
    while( mask >> (*result % 32) )
        (*result)--;
}
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, except for the indentation of the code. Each structural level should be indented by the same amount of spaces. Typical values are 2, 4 or 8. Your mixture of 2 and 3 is hard to read.

Comment: @RolandIllig the use of 3 spaces wasn't meant, thanks for noticing. I fixed it.

Comment: Agree. I would go farther and say that I prefer to use no-braces or braces for the whole chain. Using one braced and one without kind of confuses me, and you can insert a brace without even increasing the lines of code, in this case.